# What scope for html.erb in Sublime Text?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, sublimetext3, sublimetext-snippet

I'm writing a snippet for html.erb files,
but I can't understead what should I write in scope tag.
 
When I press ctrl+shift+alt+p it shows to me "text.html.ruby text.html.basic"

html.erb

```
<p>test</p>
<%= 'test' %>
```

The snippet

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[test]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>test</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html.ruby</scope>
</snippet>
```

or

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[test]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>test</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html.basic</scope>
</snippet>
```

Doesn't work but it's all right with the snippet cuz when I change the scope to "source.ruby" all is working fine.

P.S correct my english.

Comment: This is not a ROR problem, but with html, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36129043/how-to-create-a-snippet-for-html-in-sublime-text/36129044#36129044) question.

Answer (score 0):

Correct tag for erb is:

```
<scope>text.html.ruby</scope>
```

You problem in content section, because tabTrigger "test" will be replaced by same value "test". There should be something like this:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<%= ${1:test} %>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>test</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html.ruby</scope>
</snippet>
```