# How to create a snippet for html in Sublime Text?

Tags: html, sublimetext-snippet

I made a snippet which works on other scopes, but won't with html.
When i'm typing "test" just nothing happens.
Why?

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[test]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>test</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to type "<test" instead of "test".

Comment: @Hassan Saghir what do you mean?
That i'm answering to my own question?

Comment: Yep, you answering to you own question !

Comment: @HassanSaghir it's okay to answer to your own question. read [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions) pls.